# Error Code 310007. A primary key field cannot be nullable

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, java, fuel-sdk

I am creating Data Extension via Java SDK(Axis).

When I add new field, it's `isNillable` attribute is `null` by default. If I leave it as `null` and create DE, ExactTarget returns me OK status, but, on UI, when I open my DE, all fields are marked as `nullable`.

If I set `isNillable` with `false|true` value, same result, all fields `nullable`.

Seems like other parameter decides what value it should take.

So, If I check field as PK and post to create DE, ExactTarget responses with following error:

`310007 A primary key field cannot be nullable.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally not obvious, but you actually want to be using IsRequired=true on your primary key field, not isNillable.  This is how you make something not nullable.